# Positions where #__PURE__ is meaningful/useful

Tags: javascript, webpack

https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-a-function-call-as-side-effect-free says

> It is possible to tell webpack that a function call is side-effect-free (pure) by using the `/*#__PURE__*/` annotation. It can be put in front of function calls to mark them as side-effect-free. Arguments passed to the function are not being marked by the annotation and may need to be marked individually. When the initial value in a variable declaration of an unused variable is considered as side-effect-free (pure), it is getting marked as dead code, not executed and dropped by the minimizer.

My questions:

1. When is it useful to mark arguments as pure? Naively it seems we can either find the variable is unused and exclude it, or not. But I can't think of a case where we could shake only some arguments.
2. If I have

   ```
   const shape = /*#__PURE__*/ PropTypes.shape({
     x: PropTypes.array(...),
     ...
   });
   ```

   can it be useful to mark the `PropTypes.array` call as well? I don't believe marking the argument of `shape` would have any effect since it isn't a function call.
3. Does `export default /*#__PURE__*/ withSomeHOC(withAnotherHOC(...))` work as expected, or does it need to be written as

   ```
   const Component = /*#__PURE__*/ withSomeHOC(withAnotherHOC(...));
   export default Component;
   ```

   instead?

I have tested in some specific cases, but wanted to get a general answer. I'm focusing on Webpack, but answers for other bundlers are welcome as well.